# -javaagent: option recognised as a command

Tags: java, processbuilder, javaagents

In an application I am writing, I need to use the javaagent option to call an external jar in the same folder as my current jar file. When I run the code from the jar file, I get told: "Error: Could not find or load main class  -javaagent:" but when I am running it from a batch file, it works as excepted.

I am using a ProcessBuilder to start the application:

```
String java = System.getProperty("java.home") + File.separatorChar + "bin" + File.separatorChar +"java.exe";
File transagent = new File(pluginDir + File.separatorChar + "TransAgent.jar");
String doublequote = String.valueOf('"');
List<String> commandlist = new ArrayList<String>();
commandlist.add(java);
commandlist.add(" -javaagent:");
commandlist.add(doublequote);
commandlist.add(transagent.getAbsolutePath());
commandlist.add(doublequote);
for(int i = 0; i < commandlist.size(); i++){
    String part = commandlist.get(i);
    System.out.print(part);
}
System.out.println();
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command(commandlist);
pb.redirectError(Redirect.appendTo(errorfile));
pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(logfile));
try {
    pb.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But, when I go to the error file, I see "Error: Could not find or load main class  -javaagent:"

This would usually be thrown if the option isn't valid, but I've checked the dash to work file. And I put what printed from the application in a batch file, and it worked fine. Why?

Comment: Start off by not putting a space in it. There's also no need for the `doublequote`, this is one of reasons to use `ProcessBuilder` this way, each element in the `List` will become it's own parameter/argument

Comment: I tried it without the space but then it said "Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : " without telling me what's missing

Comment: Troubleshooting tip for future use: write a small application that prints out the command line, and use it for diagnosing problems like this.

Comment: I have done that inside the "for" loop where I get each part of the command line and print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code below:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-javaagent:"+transagent.getAbsolutePath(), "YouMainClass");
    pb.redirectError(Redirect.appendTo(errorfile));
    pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(logfile));

    try
    {
        pb.start();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: It worked for me once, but now when I try it I get: Error: Could not find or load main class YouMainClass